# What are some of the applications of Helium-Neon lasers?

Tags: laser, photonics

I've worked with them in the lab and while they have a very nice Gaussian beam profile, they are tedious to say the least to align(2 hours to align a HeNe laser compared with 5 minutes to align a diode laser of the same wavelength)and their beam power output is extremely unstable. They also don't last very long since the gas tube leaks(and given that they cost > $1000(US) for a laser that can barely put out 3mW I think it's not a good investment). From what I've read, the only practical application they have is in holography.But do they have any other uses outside of experimental optics labs?

Comment: Perhaps here? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium%E2%80%93neon_laser#Applications

Comment: These days perhaps not so much. But they used to be about the cheapest laser you could get, 40 years ago.

Comment: When you say "diode laser," are you talking about a simple, sealed module such as you would find in a cheap laser pointer? or are you talking about an [external cavity diode laser](https://www.rp-photonics.com/external_cavity_diode_lasers.html)? I don't know much about the latter, but I'm guessing that the price and the maintenance issues are going to be somewhat similar to a HeNe laser. If the HeNe laser that you're talking about is good for holography, then that means it has a coherence length of at least a few tens of cm. You won't get that from an itty-bitty diode module.

Comment: @SolomonSlow it was not a laser pointer, but a fairly inexpensive diode laser and not an external cavity diode laser. But one problem with HeNe and other gas lasers is that the sealed gas tube leaks. That makes their shelf life and operational life much shorter than a solid state laser(diode or otherwise).